# Getting params from URL in model's create method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a way to get the params from URL in the create method?

My URL for the "new" view is:

```
/model_name/new?other_model_id=100
```

I would like to be able to alter the model with ID 100 when I create a new model. I've tried calling params[:other_model_id] in my "create" method, which returned nil and I tried setting the following variable in my "new" method:

```
@other_model = Model.find(params[:other_model_id])
```

I have a field called "other_versions" in my model, which is an array of model IDs. When I create a new model I want to add the new model's ID to the array of model IDs in the old model.

Comment: I don't really get what you're asking.  It sounds like you want to edit the model with id of 100?  Why do you want to do this after creating a new model?  Can you not just redirect to the edit action for the model with the id of 100?

Comment: I have a field called "other_versions" in my model, which is an array of model IDs. When I create a new model, I want to add the new models id to the array of model IDs in the old model, of which the ID is in the URL. Hope that helps a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use the `after_create`filter (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html) and just add the "other_model" id on an hidden field on your create/edit form?

Please make sure, if you are using Rails >4, to add that parameter on your strong parameters (http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html) otherwise it will always be empty when you check on `params`.

Comment: I did something similar to this, I added a "parent_model" field to my model, and put it on my form as a hidden input. Then, I changed the value of that input to the ID in my URL using jQuery. Finally, I created a method in my model.rb file that altered the parent model, which I then called after the model saved in the "create" method in the controller (since after_create was giving me some other issues). Thank you so much for your help!